# Set variable/execute function before runtime in java(android)?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a class with static variables, but I'm not sure how to set the variables before runtime. This is what I'm attempting to do...

```
public class Defaults {

public static String[] abc = new String[2];

public static void functionToExecuteBeforeRuntime{

    abc[0] = "a";
    abc[1] = "b";
    abc[2] = "c";

}
```

}

It's supposed to set `abc` using `functionToExecuteBeforeRuntime` before runtime so other classes can access it with `Defaults.abc`,however it is never executed. How can I achieve this? Any help appreciated

-oh i'm not sure if this makes a difference but I don't think with andriod I can use the `public static main()` guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that example, you could just initialize it there, like:

`public static String[] abc = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};`

For just a general way of doing complex initialization for your static fields, I'm not sure, but I believe Android has [Static Initializer Blocks](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), which work like:

```
public class Test
{
 public static String[] stuff = new String[2];
 static
 {
  stuff[0] = "Hi";
  stuff[1] = "Bye";
 }
}
```

Or you could use static functions to do, basically, the same thing.

```
public class Test
{
 public static String[] stuff = initializeStuff();
 public static String[] initializeStuff()
 {
  String[] arr = new String[2];
  arr[0] = "Hi";
  arr[1] = "Bye";
  return arr;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it into a static initialization block of code like so:

```
private static String[] stuff;

static {
  stuff = new String[] {"1", "2"};
}
```